# Spyder: importerror: cannot import name constants

Tags: python, importerror, spyder

Ubuntu 16.04
Python 2.7
Anaconda 2

I have Anaconda2 installed. This includes the spyder IDE, according to google.

```
$ spyder
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/bin/spyder", line 7, in <module>
    from spyder.app.start import main
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 13, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 27, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name constants
```

Doesn't work:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge spyder
$ sudo apt-get install spyder
```

Doesn't work:

```
$ conda uninstall spyder
$ conda install spyder
```

Googling the error doesn't help me along. I'm not a programmer. Python libraries and Anaconda directories and IDE repositories, are all Greek to me. Might be useful information for those who actually know how things work: importing scipy.io also gives me importerrors.

Where is the fault and how do I resolve it?

**EDITS**

```
$ conda update chardet
```

gives:

```
/home/pieter/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.22) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

and

```
$ conda update urllib3
```

gives:

```
/home/pieter/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.22) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.


$ conda info spyder
```

gives:

```
absurdly long, long, long list of replies
```

of which the last is:

```
spyder 3.2.4 py27h04a3490_0
---------------------------
file name   : spyder-3.2.4-py27h04a3490_0.tar.bz2
name        : spyder
version     : 3.2.4
build string: py27h04a3490_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
size        : 2.5 MB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
md5         : ed9729850ec1ab3c83d87b422e687bc5
platform    : None
subdir      : linux-64
timestamp   : 1508356637551
url         : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64/spyder-3.2.4-py27h04a3490_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    chardet >=2.0
    jedi >=0.9
    nbconvert
    numpydoc
    pickleshare
    psutil
    pycodestyle
    pyflakes
    pygments >=2.0
    pylint
    pyqt
    python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0
    pyzmq
    qtawesome >=0.4.1
    qtconsole >=4.2
    qtpy >=1.2.0
    rope >=0.9.4
    sphinx
```

myEnv:

```
(myEnv) pieter@t:~/bagfile_analysis$ spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pieter/anaconda2/envs/myEnv/bin/spyder", line 4, in <module>
    import re
  File "/home/pieter/anaconda2/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... have you tried [THIS](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4514) already?

Also, how exactly did you install spyder? Maybe you didn't install it in the right environemnt(in your case probably the default *root/base* environment)

**I'd recommend installing it via conda in the terminal!** Also make sure you have installed it in the right environment:

get a list of all your environments:

```
$ conda env list
```

install it in a specific environment:

```
$ conda install --name "your env" spyder
```

and of course make sure you got the latest anaconda version:

```
$ conda update -n base conda
```

## EDIT

ok now we know you only have your base environment.

since chardet is a dependency of spyder let's update those two packages first to be sure...

```
$ conda update chardet

$ conda update urllib3
```

Let's go on and check your spyder.
Does it work now?

if not try this:

```
$ conda info spyder
```

what do you get?

you should get a very long list, but only the last entry is of importance, something like that:

```
spyder 3.2.5 py27_0
-------------------
file name   : spyder-3.2.5-py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : spyder
version     : 3.2.5
build string: py27_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
size        : 2.5 MB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : MIT
md5         : 5ec8ffcda103c23c81005a5aed0c91e7
platform    : None
subdir      : osx-64
timestamp   : 1514270782022
url         : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64/spyder-3.2.5-py27_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    chardet >=2.0
    cloudpickle
    jedi >=0.9
    nbconvert
    numpydoc
    pickleshare
    psutil
    pycodestyle
    pyflakes
    pygments >=2.0
    pylint
    pyqt
    python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0
    python.app
    pyzmq
    qtawesome >=0.4.1
    qtconsole >=4.2
    qtpy >=1.2.0
    rope >=0.9.4
    sphinx
```

if you don't get anything back you have installed spyder in the wrong environment and you can skip step 1:

STEP 1:
uninstall spyder again.

```
$ conda uninstall spyder
```

STEP 2:
reinstall it

```
$ conda install spyder
```

### EDIT II

Have you had a look at the link I posted?

the only other thing that comes is in my mind is trying a different environment (for example called "myEnv").

```
$ conda create --name myEnv spyder
```

then activate the environment and try to launch spyder. conda tells you how to activate the environment, but i guess it's the same as for mac os:

```
$ source activate myEnv

$ spyder

$ source deactivate
```

if that doesn't work you can remove the environment again.

```
$ conda remove --name myEnv *
```

In any case the dependency error is weird...

Comment: you have to add it in your question i guess.

Comment: could you copy your latest spyder version info in here? not the whole list of versions..

Comment: As to the link - I have no idea what tensorflow is, or what my kernels are (probably not even a sentence that makes sense). Also: am not on mac os, if I gave that impression. I'm on linux ubuntu 16.04.